# wrapping `View` in `UITableviewcell` with troubled

Tags: swift, swiftui

When i tried to wrapping `View` into `UITableviewcell` . Sometime the bottom padding of `View`  was wrong.
Any body known what is reason?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwoCl.png

My current code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //swiftlint:disable force_cast
        let tableViewCell = EventCell() //tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: control.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! EventCell

        var rootView: AnyView
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let data = getEventAndTodayDivider(indexPath: indexPath)
            rootView = AnyView(AgendaTopEventView(allDays: self.getAllDayEvents(indexPath: indexPath),
                                                  data: data.0, todayDividerType: data.1))
        } else {
            let data = getEventAndTodayDivider(indexPath: indexPath)
            rootView = AnyView(AgendaEventView(data: data.0, todayDividerType: data.1))
        }

        if tableViewCell.host == nil {
            let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: rootView)
            tableViewCell.host = controller

            let tableCellViewContent = controller.view!
            tableViewCell
                .contentView
                .addSubview(tableCellViewContent)
            tableCellViewContent
                .topAnchor
                .constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
            tableCellViewContent
                .leftAnchor
                .constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
            tableCellViewContent
                .bottomAnchor
                .constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            tableCellViewContent
                .rightAnchor
                .constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
            tableCellViewContent
                .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        } else {
            // reused cell, so just set other SwiftUI root view
            tableViewCell.host?.rootView = rootView
        }
        tableViewCell.host?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        tableViewCell.backgroundColor = .clear
        tableViewCell.selectionStyle = .none
        return tableViewCell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not testable, so just by code reading, try the following..

```
  if tableViewCell.host == nil {
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: rootView)
        tableViewCell.host = controller

        let tableCellViewContent = controller.view!
        tableCellViewContent
            .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // << here !!
        tableViewCell
            .contentView
            .addSubview(tableCellViewContent)
        tableCellViewContent
            .topAnchor
            .constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableCellViewContent
            .leftAnchor
            .constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        tableCellViewContent
            .bottomAnchor
            .constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        tableCellViewContent
            .rightAnchor
            .constraint(equalTo: tableViewCell.contentView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    } else {
        // reused cell, so just set other SwiftUI root view
        tableViewCell.host?.rootView = rootView
        tableViewCell.host?.updateViewConstraints()  // << this !!
    }
```